# Can't sell Imperial items

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I can't sell my surplus imperial items. When I check inventory it just tells me to summon a supply officer to make more

Answer (score 1):

The Imperial items are not for sale like those of the levels above.

They are for completing Imperial quests that Darth Vader assigns if you tap on the level below the Arrivals floor.  This is the level with his hologram on it.

When you tap there, he will assign you to build a series of items in exchange for a bonus in credits. These bonuses can quickly add up, some of the higher ones reach >200,000 credits.

Comment: So no quest, no sale?

Comment: That is correct.